# Change edge name that appears in popup on hover

Tags: pharo, roassal

How can I change a text that appears whe you hover over edge in Roasal? I have not found this anywhere on the web

Comment: You misspelled Roassal in the tag

Comment: @dschenk thank you. I always miss that `s`…

Answer (score 1):

You can add a popup (with custom styling) to a single edge in the following way:

```
popup := ROPopup text: 'some text'.
popup textColor: Color black.
popup box color: (Color r: 0.9 g: 0.9 b: 0.9); borderWidth: 1; borderColor: (Color r: 0.8 g: 0.8 b: 0.8).
aROEdge @ popup.
```

Comment: Can I use a block to set functionality for all edges?

Answer (score 1):

A complete example of it could be:

```
view := ROView new.
el1 := ROBox green element extent: 50 @ 50.
el2 := ROBox blue element extent: 50 @ 50.
el1 @ RODraggable.
el2 @ RODraggable.
el2 translateTo: 50 @ 50.

aROEdge := ROEdge lineFrom: el1 to: el2.
(aROEdge getShape: ROLine) width: 5.

popup := ROPopup text: 'some text'.
popup textColor: Color black.
popup box color: (Color r: 0.9 g: 0.9 b: 0.9); borderWidth: 1; borderColor: (Color r: 0.8 g: 0.8 b: 0.8).
aROEdge @ popup.

view addAll: { el1 . el2 . aROEdge }.
view open
```